# Magento2 Migration Redirects to the old Server

Tags: magento2, redirect

I moved my magento2 installation to a new server with a new IP address. I used this documentation for my backups (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-backup.html)

But I don't know how change old IP address.
I have a redirection to my old IP address.

Thanks for reply

Clement.

Comment: check your apache site configuration file and change the path.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157396)

Answer (score 3):

Go to your database and find table `core_config_data` In following table, search for following entities and change their values to your new server URL address:

```
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url
```

Comment: In addition to this you will need to clear cache.  Delete `var/cache` folder

Answer (score 1):

Change fields in DB table *core_config_data* with paths *web/unsecure/base_url* and *web/secure/base_url* to suitable url address. This should help.

Answer (score 0):

If any time you exported your system config values using `bin/magento app:config:dump` then remember to check **app/etc/env.php** file.

This file may have a node like following.

```
'web' => [
    'unsecure' => [
        'base_url' => 'https://test.example.com/',
        'base_link_url' => '{{unsecure_base_url}}',
        'base_static_url' => null,
        'base_media_url' => null
    ],
    'secure' => [
        'base_url' => 'https://test.example.com/',
        'base_link_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}',
        'base_static_url' => null,
        'base_media_url' => null
    ],
    'default' => [
        'front' => 'cms'
    ],
    'cookie' => [
        'cookie_path' => null,
        'cookie_domain' => null
    ]
]
```

Remember to change the base url to new url here also.